# Packet problem - Not receiving anything after the first few packets

Tags: sockets, networking, actionscript, chat

I'm trying to use the following code to build a simple chat program in Actionscript. Unfortunately, not everything seems to be transmitted correctly, because it doesn't receive any packets after the first few packets (so not all of the text updates get received). I used Wireshark and saw that all of the packets were being transmitted, so I'm not sure why Flash isn't processing all of them. Here's my code:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:Canvas id="login">
    <mx:TextInput id="host" text="Host name"></mx:TextInput>
    <mx:TextInput id="pswd" text="Key 1" keyDown="changePSWD()" y="30"></mx:TextInput>
    <mx:TextInput id="key" text="Key 2" keyDown="changeKey()" y="60"></mx:TextInput>
    <mx:TextInput id="port" text="Port" y="90"></mx:TextInput>
    <s:Button label="Connect" y="90" x="150" click="doConnect()"></s:Button><s:Button y="120" label="Listen for connections (Don't worry. We'll automatically reconfigure your router)" click="listen()"></s:Button>
</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Canvas id="chatScreen" visible="false">
    <s:TextArea id="mainchat" keyUp="sendTxt()" width="500" height="500"></s:TextArea>
</mx:Canvas>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
   import flash.net.Socket;
   import flash.system.Security;
   import flash.utils.ByteArray;
   private var nativeSocket:Socket = new Socket();
    private function init():void {
        Security.allowDomain("*");
        nativeSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connected);

        nativeSocket.connect("localhost", 337);

        }
        private function sendTxt():void {
            //Send update signal
            var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            //Signal type
            buffer.writeByte(0);
            //Signal data
            buffer.writeUTF(mainchat.text);
            buffer.position = 0;
            securesocket.Write(buffer);
            securesocket.Flush();
        }
        private var securesocket:NativeSocket;
        private function changeKey():void {
            key.displayAsPassword = true;
        }
        private function changePSWD():void {
            pswd.displayAsPassword = true;
        }

        private function fail():void {
            ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Failed to establish a connection to the remote host.");
        }
        private function success(socket:NativeSocket):void {
            login.visible = false;
            chatScreen.visible = true;

            securesocket = socket;
            securesocket.onRecv = parseData;
            securesocket.ReadAsync(4086);
        }
        private function doConnect():void {
            nativeInterface.openSocket(host.text, int(port.text), pswd.text, key.text, success, fail);

        }
        private function parseData(buffer:ByteArray, sender:NativeSocket):void {
            try {
            buffer.position = 0;
            var opcode:int = buffer.readByte();
            if (opcode == 0) {
                mainchat.text = buffer.readUTF();
            }
            }catch (Exception:Error) {

            }
            securesocket.ReadAsync(9077);
        }
        private function clientConnectedToServer(endpoint:String, socket:NativeSocket):void {
            try {
            ExternalInterface.call("alert", endpoint + " has connected to Chat. The server listening socket will now close and you may begin your secure chat session.");
            }catch (Exception:Error) {

            }
            mainserv.Stop();
            //Begin chat
            securesocket = socket;
            securesocket.onRecv = parseData;
            securesocket.ReadAsync(999999);
            chatScreen.visible = true;
        }
        private var mainserv:server;
        private function serverConnected(socket:server):void {
            socket.clientConnect = clientConnectedToServer;
        mainserv = socket;

        login.visible = false;

            }
        private function listen():void {
            nativeInterface.listenSocket(int(port.text), "xChat-server" + port.text, pswd.text, key.text, serverConnected);
        }
        private var nativeInterface:NativeInterface;
        private function connected(evt:Event):void {
            nativeInterface = new NativeInterface(nativeSocket);
            }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash/Flex applications communicate correctly after implementing a cross-domain policy

file which you communicate with on port #843

Take a look at [Cross-domain Policy File Specifications](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html)

This is a sample policy-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I already did that. There are no exceptions being thrown (such as SecurityException; which would occur if there was NOT a cross-domain policy file), and it CAN communicate properly for the first few packets, but it fails later on in the connection for some reason. It just doesn't receive the data for some reason....

Comment: @IDWMaster Please let me understand this correctly, you checked on Wireshark and the packets are being sent in the right form but what if this was about the Endiannes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness ?

Comment: OK. That was the problem! The Indian got changed during program execution from BIG_ENDIAN to SMALL_ENDIAN. I'll mark this as the solution.